# Schur covering group

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

It is known that every finite group has a Schur covering group.
I'm eager to know  every finite group can be considered as a Schur covering group of a group.
If it is not true in general, under what conditions is possible.

Yours,

Taj

Comment: I think it can't be true for a finite simple group with non-trivial Schur multiplier, eg, $A_n$ for $n>4$. I don't know about a general condition though.

Comment: You asked this question in the Group Pub Forum; it was pointed out there that $(2,2)$ is not a covering group, and that many finite abelian groups are not covering groups.

Comment: Voting to close because this question has already been asked and answered on the group pub forum.

Comment: @StefanKohl: It was asked there, and the first question was answered (whether any finite group is a Schur cover); the second question was not answered there yet, last I checked. I'm more bothered by the fact that the OP decided to ask the same question in several fora rather than pose the question in one and then wait to see if he would get a satisfactory answer there. It invites wasted effort by others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the second part of my question is still open.

Comment: @Taj: And then you re-posted your *full* question in Group Pub Forum. But I for one don't plan to think about it, because I don't want to have to check all the places where you may have asked the question to see if my efforts are wasted or not. You should have posted in one place, and then **waited**. If no answer was forthcoming after a reasonable time, then go ahead and post elsewhere, *mentioning* that you had already posted the question at the other place.